# App goes into Break Mode when I try to use Json with HttpClient

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, httpclient

I am trying to post data from my app from a register page to a web service (testing with requestb.in) however when I try to use the below code it puts the app into break mode, then when I use break points to find where the problem is it just shows that "await PostRequest(...)" is causing the problem.
I have installed System.Net.Http on both the Portable project and the android project.

```
public async Task<JObject> PostAsync(string uri, string data)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(data));

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return await Task.Run(() => JObject.Parse(content));
}
```

Then for the button clicked where this method is called:

```
async void NextBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs)
{
   await PostAsync("https://requestb.in/MYURL", Username.Text);
}
```

Username.Text is the string from an entry field in the XAML class, This will recreate my problem

Comment: FYI as a side note: [you are using HttpClient wrong and its destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Comment: You asked this same question less than 24 hours ago.  Do not post the same question multiple times.

Comment: @Jason i have edited it and no one answered the last one

Comment: @Jason The code is different and I have made it so that it can be reproduced, just the problem is the same

Comment: I've re-opened - please delete your other question to prevent any confusion

Comment: Shouldn't you also use a JSON for the request body?

Comment: @DanielRusznyak What do you mean? would you be able to show me?

Comment: `await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(data));` 
You are sending the data as a raw text content. Your server might be looking for a JSON body:
`var jsonData = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

Comment: @Ciaran what does the server expect. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve? You explain the symptoms but we need to get an idea of the end goal.

Comment: @Nkosi well i want to be able to post data as a json into a web service through the HttpClient

Comment: @Ciaran ok. cool I get that much. what are you suppose to be sending to the service. In your original post you were creating parameters to send. are you suppose to be sending a model?

Comment: @Ciaran does the app have permission to use wifi/make network calls?

Comment: @nkosi I just wanted to send the individual entry field strings so that I would be able to store them in an SQL database after the web service takes them

Comment: @Nkosi yes it has permission for Internet under Android manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the generic method I made to post data to an API.

As [@maccettura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2457029/maccettura) pointed out above, it is [best practice to reuse HttpClient](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and I've included that in the code, below.

## HttpClient Post

```cs
static readonly Lazy<HttpClient> _clientHolder = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => CreateHttpClient(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)));
static HttpClient Client => _clientHolder.Value;

protected static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostObjectToAPI<T>(string apiUrl, T data)
{
    var stringPayload = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    try
    {
        return await Client.PostAsync(apiUrl, httpContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return null;
    }
}

static HttpClient CreateHttpClient(TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    client.Timeout = timeout;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));

    return client;
}
```

This snippet was taken from my `BaseHttpClientService.cs` that I copy/paste into any app that needs to use `HttpClient`:
https://github.com/brminnick/XamList/blob/master/XamList/Services/BaseHttpClientService.cs

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot your application using UWP so that you can see what kind of exception it is throwing. Try also to downgrade the two Nuget packages.